# Is this the correct way to extract counts from a Concurrent Hash Map without missing some or double counting?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Working on something where I'm trying to count the number of times something is happening. Instead of spamming the database with millions of calls, I'm trying to sum the updates in-memory and then dumping the results into the database once per second (so like turning 10 +1s into a single +10)

I've noticed some strange inconsistency with the counts (like there should be exactly 1 million transactions but instead there are 1,000,016 or something).

I'm looking into other possible causes but I wanted to check that this is the correct way of doing things. The use case is that it needs to be eventually correct, so it's okay as long as the counts aren't double counted or dropped.

Here is my sample implementation.

```
public class Aggregator {
    private Map<String, LongAdder> transactionsPerUser = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private StatisticsDAO statisticsDAO;

    public Aggregator(StatisticsDAO statisticsDAO) {
        this.statisticsDAO = statisticsDAO;
    }

    public void incrementCount(String userId) {
        transactionsPerId.computeIfAbsent(userId, k -> new LongAdder()).increment();
    }

    @Scheduled(every = "1s")
    public void sendAggregatedStatisticsToDatabase() {
        for (String userId : transactionsPerUser.keySet()) {
            long count = transactionsPerUser.remove(userId).sum();
            statisticsDAO.updateCount(userId, count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is meaningless for one thread to try to obtain a correct count while other threads are concurrently changing it. The best you can hope to do is have the threads that change it maintain some atomic `count` variable, but even then, when the other thread asks for the count, it will only ever be able to know what the count _was_ at some recent moment in the past. It can't know what the count is _now_ unless it locks out all of the other threads.

Comment: I suppose I'm not too concerned about what the exact count is now, just that the count will be eventually correct when the dust settles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have updates dropped in the following scenario:

- Thread A calls incrementCount, and finds an already existing LongAdder instance for the given userId, this instance is returned from computeIfAbsent.
- Thread B is at the same time handling a sendAggregatedStatisticsToDatabase call, which removes that LongAdder instance from the map.
- Thread B calls sum() on the LongAdder instance.
- Thread A, still executing that same incrementCount invocation, now calls increment() on the LongAdder instance.

This update is now dropped. It will not be seen by the next invocation of sendAggregatedStatisticsToDatabase, because the increment() call happened on an instance that was removed from the map in between the calls to computeIfAbsent() and increment() in the incrementCount method.

You might be better off reusing the LongAdder instances by doing something like this in sendAggregatedStatisticsToDatabase:

```
        LongAdder longAdder = transactionsPerUser.get(userId);
        long count = longAdder.sum();
        longAdder.add(-count);
```

Comment: A great explanation for what's going wrong and a good fix based on what I had listed in the question, so I accepted the answer, but there's actually one potential issue that I didn't explicitly mention. Since it doesn't actually remove old LongAdder instances, then map will eventually be cluttered. For example, even if the user doesn't make any more transactions for the next twenty four hours, we still have to iterate over that userId every second. It's probably fast enough but that's just something I thought of as one of the reasons that I used remove in the first place

Comment: Yes, that is a good point, and I can't think of a good solution off the top of my head. You may have to increase the complexity of your logic significantly in order to achieve both correctness and good performance.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the answer of @NorthernSky. My answer should be seen as an alternative solution to the problem. Specifically addressing the comments on the accepted answer, saying that a correct and performant solution would be more complex.

I would propose to use a producer/consumer pattern here, using an unbounded blocking queue. The producers call `incrementCount()` which just adds a userId to the queue.

The consumer is scheduled to run every second and reads the queue into a `HashMap`, and then pushes the map's data to the DAO.

```
public class Aggregator {
    private final Queue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    private final StatisticsDao statisticsDAO;

    public Aggregator(StatisticsDao statisticsDAO) {
        this.statisticsDAO = statisticsDAO;
    }

    public void incrementCount(String userId) {
        queue.add(userId);
    }

    @Scheduled(every = "1s")
    public void sendAggregatedStatisticsToDatabase() {
        int size = queue.size();
        HashMap<String, LongAdder> counts = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            counts.computeIfAbsent(queue.remove(), k -> new LongAdder()).increment();
        }
        counts.forEach((userId, adder) -> statisticsDAO.updateCount(userId, adder.sum()));
    }
}
```

Even better would be to not have a scheduled consumer, but one that keeps reading from the queue into a local `HashMap` until a timout happens or a size threshold is reached, or even when the queue is empty.
Then it would process the current map and push it entirly into the DAO, clear the map and start reading the queue again until the next time there's enough data to process.

Comment: This implementation is also really nice. I never considered producer/consumer so this led me in a really interesting direction. I actually have a follow-up question for this implementation too :)

Comment: The reason that I chose the Map-LongAdder implementation initially was that we're actually dealing with a rather high throughput and spiky usage. Think hundreds of thousands of transactions per userId, sometimes spiking to millions of transactions in a second for brief periods. I've read that the performance of queues can degrade substantially when they're "too full", is that something that might happen here? - This is one case where I wish I could post my actual code, but the key that I need to use isn't a String (userId), it's actually an Object, so memory might become a problem.

Comment: A LinkedBlockingQueue is unbounded, it's backed by a linked list. It's not too full as there is no capacity restriction other than memory. 
One of the advantages of the producer/consumer is that you can have more than one consumer. If one consumer is not enough to keep up, you can have multiple, and keep the queue relatively empty, only a burst in production would see a rise in size. The size of the maps can be controlled by how often they're processed.

Comment: The key may not be a string, but the counting doesn't need the full object. If the size of the objects is a problem, use their identifying information as a separate key object.

Comment: Note also that I've used LongAdder for convenience, but a simpler counting object that isn't thread safe would certainly suffice.

Comment: Thank you for all of your feedback

Comment: If an extra thread is not an issue, that thread could also continuously aggregate from queue to map (now done once per second). The `sendAggregatedStatisticsToDatabase` method can then swap the aggregated map used by the thread for an empty one (atomically) and send out the data in the aggregated map it got from the thread.

Comment: @Emmef I fear that won't work, as before the atomic swap of the map a thread could have gotten hold of one of the LongAdder instances in it, and then only call `increment()` on it after you've processed it in the thread that did the map switch.